# Bundler problem building native extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

I'm running bundle install on my staging environment on my Ubuntu machine. It keeps failing trying to install json 1.4.6 with the native extensions.

```
 Using bundler (1.0.7) 
Installing thor (0.14.6) 
Installing railties (3.0.3) 
Installing rails (3.0.3) 
Installing geokit-rails3 (0.1.2) 
Installing json (1.4.6) with native extensions /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:483:in `build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb 

Gem files will remain installed in /u/apps/uat.nicetripper.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/json-1.4.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /u/apps/example.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/json-1.4.6/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
 from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:446:in `each'
 from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:446:in `build_extensions'
 from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:198:in `install'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/source.rb:95:in `install'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in `run'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in `run'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:225:in `install'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/bin/bundle:13
 from /usr/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
 from /usr/bin/bundle:19
```

I already have the json gem (1.4.6) gem installed on this machine and it installed with native extensions fine.

```
root@ve:/code# gem install json
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed json-1.4.6
1 gem installed
```

I don't understand why bundler is having such a problem with this. I'm running bundler 1.0.7.

Please help because json 1.4.6 has to be included as a dependency for another vital gem.

Answer (score 2):

It's very possible that the Ubuntu provided Ruby or RubyGems is broken.  I really recommend you install Ruby using RVM, as described in this post: [Ubuntu, Ruby, RVM, Rails, and You](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you).

If you still have trouble with the `json` gem even after using `rvm`, it'll likely be much easier to debug as you'll be using something closer to what most other Rubyists do.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as Simon in Ubuntu 12.04 with stock ruby 1.8. I was trying to install Redmine and Bundler (`sudo bundle install`) kept failed withthe same error when building the json gem. `sudo gem install json` worked just fine, so I did that and then installed the rest of the app's requirements with Bundler. Hope this helps someone.